# embedding a viewcontroller in containerview in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I want to embed viewcontroller in containerview in code.

I put a containerview on storyboard and I want to embed a viewcontoller on another storyboard.

I tried below but it doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "AnotherStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let vc:OtherViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OtherViewController") as OtherViewController
self.addChildViewController(vc)
containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What actually happens? What troubleshooting have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two changes for make your code working

1. Change `containerview` to `self.view`
2. Add `OtherViewController` as storyBoard ID for `OtherViewController`.

This will make your code work.